# Raspberry Pi server to avoid Packet Loss?

Tags: networking, server, vpn

I currently have terrible packet loss from my home internet. The series of hops that I am routed through are awful and it ruins the quality of my internet (gaming, videos). Is it possible to set my Rpi up as a "Rpi server" at the office I own and hop to that route instead of using the current one?  The routing is far superior from my office.

More importantly, how much data is the Rpi model B able to I/O per second as a server?  I heard it was around 30 Mbps which should be more than enough for the uses I need, but I don't know how reliable of a source it was... a typical game of what I play is around 15 MB an hour, so unless I messed up with my math it should be enough!

Comment: If your home internet loses a bunch of packets, why would connecting through your office help? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ jacobm001 Because the route my packets are sent through at home is less optimal than the route from my office.  Sending my packets to the Rpi server and then through that network would mean bypassing the route that my packets are currently sent through.

Comment: This has nothing to do with anything specific to the rPi.

Comment: @Tyson How so? The question is deliberately and directly asking about the Rpi and its capabilities.  Especially the second question...

Comment: Although there might be an aspect of *the feasibility* which is pi-specific, *the means* of doing it are off-topic: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @tear728 because it's about networking, and the rPi could be any routing system.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see how this could work out. (Set aside the question whether your employer would like the idea of you using the office network for personal purposes on that scale.)

Why would it not work? The VPN would be just a tunnel using said terrible internet connection of yours and therefore suffer equally from packet loss and other issues. Introducing another layer on that bad connection is not going improve it.

Comment: For one, I own the office.  Details like this don't matter to you or the rest of the forum.  Secondly, VPN is not the right terminology... my bad.  Let's just say "rpi server"... According to tests, my office internet make 9 hops with low packet loss, whereas my home internet makes up to 15 hops with high packet loss.  Why would sending my traffic to the "rpi server", in order to use that network and it's route, not work?

Comment: Ok, feel free to edit your question accordingly to add this information. Please share your intended network layout to make people understand how the RPi is going to help (I now assume that the Pi is not going to use the bad connection - which renders my answer moot).

Comment: Okay thanks!  I will do this.  Sorry for the confusion.  In the gaming world, VPN is a term synonymous with a server that reroutes your connection... forgot to the rest of the world it means something else.